# Select in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, select

Why the first line (select) works and the second line (second select) does not work and the outcome of the second row is the same as the first?

First line

```
(SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs WHERE domain = 'subsite.site.com.br') AS blogid,
```

Second line

```
(SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs WHERE domain = (SELECT option_value FROM wp_9_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl')) AS blogid,
```

What's wrong with my syntax, select? 
Please, give me a light, I'm two days pounding head without solution. That's just to get the ID of the sub-site..

Comment: This is really a MySQL question. So it should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: Solved...
`(SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs WHERE domain = REPLACE((SELECT option_value FROM wp_9_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'), 'http://', '')) AS blogid,`

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer so others can benefit as well.

Comment: The solution is above..

(SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs WHERE domain = REPLACE((SELECT option_value FROM wp_blogid_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'), 'http://', '')) AS blogid